# SetDNSDomain and SetDynamicDNSRegistration Powershell multiple adapters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to SetDNSDomain and SetDynamicDNSRegistration on multiple adapters in machines and I can only make changes to current active adapter. When I set the W-Fi adapter it functions correctly as it's active but, when I try and set either the docking station or internal adapter the script fails. I was using this code below but, for then life of me I can't set inactive adapters.  Anyone have any ideas as to how to get this to function properly.

...

```
clear-host

$instances = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -Namespace "root/CIMV2" #-Computername $Computer

$count = ( $instances | Measure-Object ).Count
if ( $count -eq 1 ) {
    Write-Host "1 instance:"
} else {
    Write-Host "$count instances:"
}


foreach ( $item in $instances ) {
# Set the Dell USb Docking Station
    if ($item.Description -like "Realtek USB G*") {
        $item.SetDnsDomain("clients.ad.company.com")
        $item.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($true,$true)
        write-host "****"
        Write-Host "**Description                : " $item.Description
    Write-Host "DNSDomain                    : " $item.DNSDomain
        Write-Host "FullDNSRegistrationEnabled   : " $item.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
    Write-Host "DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled : " $item.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
        write-host "****"
    }

# Set the Dell internal adapter on laptop
    if ($item.Description -like "Intel(R) Dual Ba*") {
        $item.SetDnsDomain("clients.ad.company.com")
        $item.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($true,$true)
        write-host "****"
        Write-Host "**Description                : " $item.Description
    Write-Host "DNSDomain                    : " $item.DNSDomain
        Write-Host "FullDNSRegistrationEnabled   : " $item.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
    Write-Host "DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled : " $item.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
        write-host "****"
    }

# Set the Dell Wi-Fi adapter on laptop
    if ($item.Description -like "Intel(R) Ether*") {
        $item.SetDnsDomain("clients.ad.company.com")
        $item.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($true,$true)
        write-host "****"
        Write-Host "**Description                : " $item.Description
    Write-Host "DNSDomain                    : " $item.DNSDomain
        Write-Host "FullDNSRegistrationEnabled   : " $item.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
    Write-Host "DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled : " $item.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
        write-host "****"
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using WMI, vs the built-in PowerShell network cmdlets? ```Get-NetAdapter``` and the others you list in your post title. Why not just enable/disable the target adapter as you iterate over them in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, try this, but you may need to tweak the command to meet your specific targets.

```
# List all adapters
Get-NetAdapter | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | 
    Where-Object {$PSItem.ServerAddresses -ne $null} | 
    Select-Object -Property Caption, InterfaceAlias, ServerAddresses
}

# Set all adapters
Get-NetAdapter | 
ForEach-Object {
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name $PSItem.InterfaceName
    Set-DNSDomain -InterfaceIndex $PSItem.InterfaceIndex -DomainName 'SomeDomain.com'
    Set-DynamicDNSRegistration -InterfaceIndex $PSItem.InterfaceIndex -DynamicDNSRegistration Enabled
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name $PSItem.InterfaceName
}
```

Comment: Everytime I run this I keep getting a Set-DNSDomain and Set-DynamicDNSRegistration are invalid cmdlets on the system. I have no idea what may be causing that.